# How to create reports from database in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and I have three tables in the database. I need to make a report for each user from these three tables and print this report monthly. I need to know if there's a library to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using **Query Builder**. Create a method & send user_id as parameter & join all of your 3 tables for creating that list. Check [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries) for more detail about Query Builder.

Comment: although it's help you, you have down vote my answer :O :D